# C++ STL: Duplicating code due to missing base-class for iterator and reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator, polymorphism

In my current C++-project I have an STL map which maps integer keys onto objects. An algorithm returns a set of entries. The returned data depends on the algorithm's input and hence cannot be predicted:

```
  class MyClass
  {
     //...
  };

  int myAlgorithm(vector<int>::iterator inputIt)
  {
     // return a key for myMap which is calculated by the current value of inputData
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
     vector<int> inputData;
     map<int, MyClass> myMap;
     //<fill map with some data>
     //<fill inputData>

     vector<MyClass> result;

     for (vector<int>::iterator it = inputData.begin(); it != inputData.end(); it++)
     {
        int myMapKey = myAlgorithm(*it);
        // count() > 0 means "check whether element exists. Performance can be improved by replacing
        //    the operator[] and count() calls by map::find(). However, I want to simplify things
        //    in this example.
        if (myMap.count(myMapKey) > 0)
        {
           // in some cases there is no entry in myMap
           result.push_back(myMap[myMapKey]);
        }
     }
  }
```

As mentioned in the example I can replace `map::count()` and `operator[]`-calls with find. The [STL-reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) says that map::find()'s complexity is logarithmic in size (`O(log n)`).

I discovered that in most cases the entries in myMap are very close for two sequent entries in the result. Therefore I came to the conclusion that I would achieve better performance if I replaced the map.find() calls by iterators:

```
     map<int, MyClass>::iterator myMapIt = myMap.begin();
     for (vector<int>::iterator it = inputData.begin(); it != inputData.end(); it++)
     {
        int myMapKey = myAlgorithm(*it);
        // just increment iterator
        while (myMapKey != myMapIt->first)
        {
           myMapIt++;
           // we didn't find anything for the current input data
           if (myMapIt == myMap::end() || myMapIt->first > myMapKey)
           {
              break;
           }
        }

        // I know that I'm checking this twice, but that's not the point of my
        //    question ;)
        if (myMapIt == myMap::end() || myMapIt->first > myMapKey)
        {
           // probably it would be better to move the iterator back to the position
           //    where we started searching, to improve performance for the next entry
           myMapIt = myMap.begin();
        }
        else
        {
           result.push_back(myMapIt.second);
        }
     }
```

This concept works but I have a big problem: Depending on the inputData, I have to search forward or backward. Consider that I call the code inside `main()` multiple times and the inputData changes for these calls. Instead of checking whether to increment or decrement the iterator inside the `while`-loop, I could decide that before entering the `for`-loop.

I thought that I'm fine with just switching the `map<>::iterator` to `map<>::reverse_iterator` and using `rbegin()`/`rend()` instead of `begin()`/`end()`. But then I realized that `reverse_iterator` and `iterator` have no common base class:

```
     map<int, MyClass>::base_iterator myIt;
     if (/* ... */)
     {
        myMapIt = myMap::begin();
        myMapEndIt = myMap::end();
     }
     else
     {
        myMapIt = myMap::rbegin();
        myMapEndIt = myMap::rend();
     }
     /* for (...) ... */
```

That would be great, but there is no `base_iterator`.

I know a simple workaround for this problem: I just need to copy the whole `for`-loop and adjust it for both cases:

```
     if (/* ... */)
     {
        /* for(...) which uses normal iterator in the while-loop */
     }
     else
     {
        /* for(...) which uses reverse iterator in the while-loop */
     }
```

Very bad ... Do you know a better solution?

Comment: would calling a function template work?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that you would achieve better performance? Do you have data to back it up? If this isn't a real bottleneck in your application you may just be making more work for yourself. That said, it's still an interesting question. :)

Comment: Due to the O(log n) complexity when using `map::find()` which isn't able to assume that the next entry is close to the current one. This code is at a very critical position, inside a few nested loops

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common base type is unnecessary when the language allows Generic Programming.

What you simply need to realize is that instead of having a long-winded linear functions with several choices along the way, you can have several nested function in which each choice lead to a different call.

Taking your example:

```
boost::any_iterator start, end;
if (/* ... */) {
  start = map.begin(), end = map.end();
} else {
  start = map.rbegin(), end = map.rend();
}

// do something with start and end
```

You can transform the code into the following:

```
// Define a free-function in the .cpp to help factor common stuff
template <typename FwdIt>
static void dosomething(FwdIt start, FwdIt end) {
  // do something with start and end
}
```

And then *inject* the call straight into the `if/else` body:

```
if (/* ... */) {
  dosomething(map.begin(), map.end());
} else {
  dosomething(map.rbegin(), map.rend());
}
```

And one good thing is that you reduce the number of changes of states within your functions and thus their complexity.

Comment: I tried that but I wonder why my whole algorithm is 5 times slower now. Is `dosomething` inlined? I can't find any reason why my idea would lead to worse performance

Comment: That was just a bug in my implementation, now it's faster

Answer (score 4):

Use a templated function. The only place in the Standard library where inheritance is used over templates is IOstreams, as far as I'm aware (and that was a mistake).

```
template<typename Iterator> ... stuff(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    // implement loop here
}
if (/*...*/) {
    stuff(map.rbegin(), map.rend());
} else {
    stuff(map.begin(), map.end());
}
```

However, I question if you would simply be better off changing to an always O(1) container, like an `unordered_map`.

Comment: Do you have more informations about unordered_map? 1. I can't imagine how that is able to work 2. I read that its complexity isn't stable and also could be O(n) in the worst case

Answer (score 3):

You could use templates:

```
 template <typename T>
 void myFunction(T start, T end)
 {
     /* for (...) ... */
 }

 map<int, MyClass>::base_iterator myIt;
 if (/* ... */)
 {
    myFunction(myMap.begin(), myMap.end());
 }
 else
 {
    myFunction(myMap.rbegin(), myMap.rend());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From c++14 if you don't want to write `template<...>` you can let compiler do it for you and use lambda instead create function template.

then call would be like that:

```
void your_function(auto &some_container, bool from_front) {                                                                                                                                  
    auto setter = [&](auto begin, auto end) {                                                                                                                                                  
      auto no_of_elements_to_change = 3;                                                                                                                                                       
      for (auto el = begin; el != end; ++el) {                                                                                                                                                 
        *el = +1000;  /// stuff you want to do with last 3 elements                                                                                                                            
        if (--no_of_elements_to_change == 0) {                                                                                                                                                 
          break;                                                                                                                                                                               
        }                                                                                                                                                                                      
      }                                                                                                                                                                                        
    };                                                                                                                                                                                         
    if (from_front) {                                                                                                                                                                          
      setter(some_container.begin(), some_container.end());                                                                                                                                    
    } else {                                                                                                                                                                                   
      setter(some_container.rbegin(), some_container.rend());                                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                                          
  }
```

With c++20 we will be probably able to do same with std::ranges.